# how to find if a string contains two dot in regular expression in php

Tags: php

I want to know if the string contains two `.`. for example if the string contains `www.example.com`, returns true ,because it has 2 `.`, otherwise has less than 1 `.` return false.

```
function containsTwoDot($array,$keyword){
   $matches = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($keyword) { return preg_match("/\b".$keyword."\b/i".$keyword, $var); });
   if($matches)
        return true;
   return FALSE;
}

$true[0]='www.sll.dl';
$false[0]='ldfjls.dlfjdflldl';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) and escape dots cause it's special chars:

```
$string = 'www.example.com';

preg_match('/\..*\./',$string);
```

Comment: if the string contains just one `.` it returns 1. some thing wrong with your code. plz check

Comment: how to implement with `or` statement. I mean it returns true if it has two dot or `http` string. how can I handle it?

Comment: use **preg_match('/(\..*\.)|(http)/',$string)**

Answer (score 5):

You can use php function `substr_count()` -

```
<?php
$text = 'www.example.com';
echo substr_count($text, '.'); // 2
?>
```

of course it doesn't return true or false .That you can manage.